# how to combine Behavior with sequential animation in qml

Tags: qt, qml, behavior, qt-quick

if you have 4 properties and each one has a Behavior block (that lets you animate if the corresponding property is changed ) if you change 4 properties then the animation will be parallel by default, but is it possible to make the Behavior blocks execute in sequence?

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls 


ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        width:196
        height:196
        color:"lightgray"

        Rectangle {
            id: box
            width:48
            height:48
            x:10
            y:10
            color: "red"
            rotation:0
            MouseArea {
                id:d
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    parent.x= parent.x==10 ? root.width - parent.width -10 : 10
                    parent.y= parent.y==10 ? root.height - parent.height -10 : 10
                    parent.rotation= parent.rotation==360 ? 0 : 360
                    parent.color=parent.color=="#ff0000" ? "teal": "red"

                }
            }

            Behavior on rotation {
                id:d1
                RotationAnimation {
                    duration: 500
                }
            }

            Behavior on x {
                id:d2
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
            Behavior on y {
                id:d3
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
            Behavior on color {
                id:d4
                ColorAnimation{
                    duration:500
                        }

            }
        
    }

}
}
```

I tried to `onClicked:{
...
d1.start()
d2.start()
...

`
but it doesn't make sense for Qml

Comment: If your scenario is like this, why don't you just use the `SequentialAnimation` itself?

Comment: I am just asking if possible to preserve `Behavior on` and somehow play them in order, I think it would be time-saving because `Behavior on` will automatically know the start and the end of the animation especially if you have complex alternating values

Comment: The problem with using `SequentialAnimation` in a `Behavior` is what should happen if you only change the `y` value and then, after 250 ms, start changing the `x` value. Should the animation for `y` paused at the middle or just instantly end to the last value? There are many possible ways that this can happen. However, based on your code, using a behavior may not be the best choice. Behaviors should be used in scenarios where you want to have a transition on a single changing property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this guide ([Using Qt Quick Behaviors with States](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-statesanimations-behaviors.html)) I've used [`State`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-state.html) and [`Transition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-transition.html) instead of [`Behavior`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-behavior.html). You can simply replace the [`SequentialAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-sequentialanimation.html) with [`ParallelAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-parallelanimation.html) to get your old behavior back.

This paragraph from the guide advises to use `Transition` and `State` to avoid unwanted behavior.

> Testing the example by quickly and repeatedly moving the mouse in to
> and out of the colored rectangle shows that the colored rectangle will
> settle into a green color over time, never returning to full red. This
> is not what we wanted! The problem occurs because we have used a
> Behavior to animate the change in color, and our state change is
> trigged by the mouse entering or exiting the MouseArea, which is
> easily interrupted.

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 196
    height: 196
    color: "lightgray"

    Rectangle {
        id: box
        width: 48
        height: 48
        x: 10
        y: 10
        color: "red"
        rotation: 0

        property bool toggle: false

        MouseArea {
            id:d
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: box.toggle = !box.toggle
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "topLeft"
                when: !box.toggle

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: box
                    color: "red"
                    x: 10
                    y: 10
                    rotation: 0
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "bottomRight"
                when: box.toggle

                PropertyChanges {
                    target: box
                    color: "teal"
                    x: root.width - box.width - 10
                    y: root.height - box.height - 10
                    rotation: 360
                }
            }
        ]

        transitions: Transition {
            SequentialAnimation {
                ColorAnimation { duration: 500 }
                RotationAnimation { duration: 500 }
                NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; duration: 500 }
                NumberAnimation { properties: "y"; duration: 500 }
                NumberAnimation { properties: "rotation"; duration: 500 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`NumberAnimation` could also be combined to move the `Rectangle` in `x` and `y` at the same time.

```
NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; duration: 500 }
NumberAnimation { properties: "y"; duration: 500 }
```

to

```
NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 500 }
```

Comment: I was believing that using `Behavior on ` would help save time because it works once the property is changed, but It apparently cannot be animated sequentially, However, Your code helped me understand new things, and now just by replacing SequentialAnimation with ParallelAnimation I get the 2 modes with a simple change, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you can assign animations directly to an event? To cover both forward and backward conditions I use two MouseAreas respectively. In the below MouseArea.onClicked events:

- I was able to decide which bits are SequentialAnimation and which bits are ParallelAnimation
- I was able to change the rotation from clockwise to anti-clockwise depending on which event was firing
- I was able to optimize the backward animation since both "x,y" go to 10

I think you'll find this approach more succinct and more customizable than when the animations were inside Behaviors.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "MouseArea.onClicked animations"
    Rectangle {
        id: root
        width:196
        height:196
        color:"lightgray"
        
        Rectangle {
            id: box
            width:48
            height:48
            x:10
            y:10
            color: "red"
            rotation:0
            
            MouseArea {
                id: forwards
                anchors.fill: parent
                enabled: box.x === 10
                onClicked: SequentialAnimation {
                    ParallelAnimation {
                        NumberAnimation { target: box; property: "x"; to: root.width - box.width - 10; duration: 500 }
                        NumberAnimation { target: box; property: "y"; to: root.height - box.height - 10; duration: 500 }
                    }
                    RotationAnimation { target: box; property: "rotation"; from: 0; to: 360; duration: 500 }
                    ColorAnimation { target: box; property: "color"; from: "teal"; to: "red"; duration: 500 }
                }
            }
            
            MouseArea {
                id: backwards
                anchors.fill: parent
                enabled: box.x !== 10
                onClicked: SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: box; properties: "x,y"; to: 10; duration: 500 }
                    RotationAnimation { target: box; property: "rotation"; from: 360; to: 0; duration: 500 }
                    ColorAnimation { target: box; property: "color"; from: "teal"; to: "red"; duration: 500 }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)